# Soap xml for Paypal API SetMobileCheckout (rolling my own objective-c request)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, soap, paypal

I have the generic structure here:

```
 <?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi= ”  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/” 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/” 
    xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”   
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/” 
><SOAP-ENV:Header> 
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns=”urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI”> 
        <Credentials xmlns=”urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents”> 
            <Username>api_username</Username> 
            <Password>api_password</Password> 
            <Signature/>     
            <Subject/> 
        </Credentials> 
    </RequesterCredentials> 
</SOAP-ENV:Header> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
    <specific_api_name_Req xmlns=”urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI”> 
        <specific_api_name_Request> 
            <Version xmlns=urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents”>service_version 
            </Version> 
            <required_or_optional_fields xsi:type=”some_type_here”>                data 
            </required_or_optional_fields> 
        </specific_api_name_Request> 
    </specific_api_name_Req> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The specific calls (SetMobileCheckout and DoMobileCheckoutPayment) I need are [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MobileCheckout.pdf)

I'm well on my way. But I am rolling my own xml request in objective-c and I I'm trying to make sure I get this right.

Has anyone got an actual example with a real request?

Bonus if it is wrapped in objective-C, but just naked xml would be great.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the HTTP POST request which uses NVP instead:

[Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app/850940#850940)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went around the problem.

You can use NVP in a HTTP POST.  This was munch easier on the iPhone.  Not sure why my SOAP response kept getting rejected, but it was too time consuming to keep going.

In search for my answer, I did run across gSoap, which may help others. I just needed to make 2 requests, so I didn't want to get wrapped up in leaning that framework.

I also ran across [wsdl2objC](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/), unfortunately, it is not working on the iPhone right now (Data Type issues).