# Using the PayPal API in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, paypal

Hello I want to use Paypal in  my iphone application, I have find the soapRequest to integrating the paypal API. My code is

```
NSString *soapMessage =  [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" 
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi= \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">\n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Header>\n" 
"<RequesterCredentials xmlns=\"urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI\">\n" 
"<Credentials xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">\n" 
"<Username>api_username</Username>\n" 
"<Password>api_password</Password>\n" 
"<Signature/>\n"     
"<Subject/>\n" 
"</Credentials>\n" 
"</RequesterCredentials>\n" 
"</SOAP-ENV:Header>\n" 
"<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" 
"<specific_api_name_Req xmlns=\"urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI\">\n" 
"<specific_api_name_Request>\n" 
"<Version xmlns=urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents”>service_version</Version>\n" 
"<required_or_optional_fields xsi:type=”some_type_here”>\n"                 
"</required_or_optional_fields>\n" 
"</specific_api_name_Request>\n" 
"</specific_api_name_Req>\n" 
"</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" 
                          "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n"];

NSLog(@"Soap message===%@",soapMessage);


NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"USER=%@&PWD=%@&SIGNATURE=%@&VERSION=57.0&METHOD=SetMobileCheckout&AMT=%.2f&CURRENCYCODE=USD&DESC=%@&RETURNURL=%@", userName, password, signature, donationAmount, @"Some Charge", returnCallURL];

NSLog(parameterString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:paypalUrlNVP];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]];

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection ){
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
//  [self displayConnectingView];

}else{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

But here I am not getting the value of paypalUrlNVP. How can i get it??
And if possible then please give some example of paypalAPI integration in iphone.

I also want to use checkout functionality.I am new in this field so I have no idea about it. So, kindly give me whole sample code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be mixing up two different ways of calling the PayPal API. You have a SOAP XML string, which you don't actually use and also then call the NVP (name value pair) API.

You need to decide which you are actually going to use.

The URLs you need to use for the NVP API are:

> API Servers for API Signature Security
>
> If you use an API signature, post the
>   request to one ofthese servers:
>
> Sandbox:
>   https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
>
> Live: https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
>   API Servers for API Certificate
>   Security
>
> If you use an API certificate, post
>   the request to oneof these servers:
>
> Sandbox:
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
>
> Live: https://api.paypal.com/nvp

As described here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

Comment: ok i have check it but i get XML Like this
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error.

It is Error so what can I do?

Comment: I think you need to enable your PayPal account for Mobile Checkout

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I think you should URL-encode the name and value parameters that you're passing in.

Comment: There is no need for that, the NVP values are in the body of the POST request, not in the URL of a GET.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at this question too ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084729/iphone-application-and-paypal)) which indicates you *will* have your application rejected by Apple. You need to look at the In App Purchase mechanisms to collect payments in an iPhone App

Comment: Selling physical goods through paypal is fine in iOS. It's only digital goods that must use in-app purchases.