# iPhone Application And PayPal

Tags: iphone, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal payment facility into my native iPhone application without using web interface so user does not have to leave from the current application. How can it be possible ? Should I use SOAP XML request/response mechanism? I come through following link
http://www.slideshare.net/paypalx/learn-how-to-use-paypal-api-to-monetize-your-mobile-app.
It contains In application Mobile Checkout via Mobile Web slide that represents the sample UI to access PayPal but how can I implement the same thing? Is it legal to use PayPal to deliver virtiual goods/Application Functionality or Apple can reject this ? Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 15):

According to apple's "App Store guidelines" document, if you are going to sell:

1. **Digital goods, upgrades or subscription**: Your only choice if Apple's In App Purchase.
2. **Charity donation**: You must redirect the user to a website using Safari, you CAN'T use a UIWebView inside the app.
3. **Physical goods**: you CAN'T user Apple's In App Purchase, you need to use a website or any other method, for example the new PayPal Library. (Apple Won't get take a 30% cut of physical goods sells)
4. **Personal donations**: (like the famous "express your gratitude and buy me a cup of coffe") you are again in item (1) and NOT on item (2).

Comment: Hi, regarding point '3.', Does Apple takes it's 30% even if we are using PayPal in the application?

Answer (score 5):

We can integrate PayPal
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paypodd/id341546114?mt=8
check my app.

Comment: please contact me Harshal, I want your help, just 5 mints, my email address is veer.developer@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

Hi Sk and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Apple is going to reject your application if you're going to use paypal in your app.
I won't advice you to use it!

However, there are the appstore and [in-app-purchases](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/inapppurchase.html).

Comment: Hi Henrik P. Hessel,
Thanks for your Answer. Using In App purchase, my concerns are: In App purchase charges 30% while Pay Pal 3% only. So why I should pay more money? let me know if other alternatives are available.

Comment: Jep, that's right. That's the exact way why apple won't allow it :/

Comment: If I open Safari from my application and use Web Interface for Payment mechanism (integrating PayPal APIs on serverside), will Apple reject it?

Answer (score 1):

Henrik is quite right. I can confirm (from personal experience) that Apple WILL reject an app that solicits payments in any way other than via in-app purcahses.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this but does that also include purchases of physical goods or just donations and virtual purchases?

Comment: The rules state you can't use in app purchase for physical goods.  However there are apps in the App Store that let you buy physical goods - like the Ocado grocery app (see UK App Store).  I've never used an app that lets you buy physical goods, so I don't know the precise payment mechanism used - perhaps it's stored credit card info attached to an existing account?

Hope that helps.