# Paypal integration in iPhone native app 

Tags: iphone, paypal, integration

I am repeating the below question to reassure that the below accepted answer is still right or now there is way to integrate PayPal in iPhone native app.

[Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

**EDIT :**
I am repeating the question only to get on the board and reopen the question to get as many good answers .

If it is valid now then if anyone can provide sample code or link .

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app

Comment: Generally, re-asking the same question just to check for updates is discouraged here.  You can comment on the answers there to see if there are any updates, or create a new, more targeted question about any new frameworks.

Comment: I assume of asking a new question because the "duplicate" question was a year old

Comment: hurray finally https://www.thepaypalblog.com/2010/04/paypal-to-open-mobile-payments-library-to-developers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still the way you need to do it.

Howeverm I would recommend using the ASIHTTPRequest framework here http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

you can get the documentation and sample code both at given link
    it's easy  to understand and integrate.

[Documentation and sample code for PayPal integration in iphone application](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides)