# itunes connect physical in app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

i know that apple does not allow physical in app purchases, but can i do a stuff like this,
when user taps buy button i will use a web view to load a url of site like amazon etc, and from there user can purchase his desired product. will apple allow this?plz. guide Regards  Saad

Comment: Apple does not allow & you want to do so. Try Android platform then.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor why not? What about Paypal sdk and Amazon mobile?

Comment: @Mat - Apple does not allow it. They want their 30% cut.  Why has so many voted this question up?

Comment: Thanx Ramhound but this post suggests that u can do this, please take a look   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355313/purchase-physical-product-from-iphone-app-without-apple-in-app-purchase, please check the answer.thanx again

Comment: @Ramhound i don't agree..i agree instead with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4025133/251513) and with the last comment posted by Saad Umar.

Comment: i thought PayPal SDK & Amazon mobile are banned years ago already?