# Will use of the PayPal iOS library get my app rejected?

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm developing an iPhone app with a subscription model, and I saw [this iOS PayPal library](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep): Apple takes 30% of revenue of everything, but PayPal takes significantly less for micro-payments (maxing out at 10%). Naturally, I became interested.

I guess what I'm confused about is this: if Apple wants everyone to use the in-app purchase library for everything (as per [this document](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf&pli=1)), why does this PayPal library even exist? Wouldn't any app that used it get rejected?

Has anyone successfully published an app in the app store that uses this library? If so, what was the purchase for? Digital goods? Physical goods? Content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[quote](https://www.x.com/thread/46302) from some forum:

> Hello, Apple policy restricts from using our library for accepting
>   digital goods.  Use our library should
>   be for hard goods, donations, personal
>   payments and services only.
>
> I hope this clarifies your question.
>
> Thank you.

---

*Update on donations.*

Apple has updated their policy (*When?*).  You can no longer use PayPal iOS for donations.

[Apple Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#charities-contributions) (Retrieved **2014-10-02 05:25pm GMT**):

> 21. Charities and contributions
>
> 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
>   21.2 The collection of charitable donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

Comment: A subscription would more than likely be considered a service.

Comment: This answer probably pre-dates the policy, but PayPal libraries are no longer acceptable for donations.  Apple Review Guidelines 21.2 - "The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS"

Answer (score 1):

There are things that you could sell by paypal in iphone apps, imagine that your app exists to promote your business, and not that your app IS your business. I mean...you have a library and use app as another channel to sell the books, or you have an hotel and use app to reserve and then pay the room! In that case you can use paypal.

You cannot use paypal, but you have to use instead in-app purchase, if you sell some additional feature for you app...

I hope this helps