# Paypal integration in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, paypal

In iPhone sdk, Can we retrieve information of all transaction for particular PayPal account?

Please Help and suggest

Thanks

Comment: This Link may be useful to you.It specifies that where to use in-app purchase or where to use paypal with iOS http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521363/1553831

Answer (score -1):

Applications having PAYPAL integration are rejected by Apple... So I suggest you to use IAP (In App Purchase)...

[Here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) You can get the full procedure step by step to do the same

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my requirement is to access Paypal related data from within the app. Hence I wanted to know if it is possible from iPhone SDK.

Comment: I do not intend to make any pay transactions of Paypal. Just want to view Paypal transaction info of a particule account from the app.

Comment: For that you have to check out the FAQS of paypal.. If paypal is providing information of the account you pass then you can surely implement it in iPhone.. But main thing that matters is `DOES PAYPAL ALLOWS YOU TO RETRIEVE INFORMATION OF ANY ACCOUNT?` and the same would be the answer to your question also

Comment: No. you can use PayPal only if you are selling a physical goods. If u want to sell digital goods (like e-books) u can use IAP.