# iphone orientation bug when using PayPal lib

Tags: iphone, paypal, orientation

I'm using the Paypal library in my iphone app. Its all working fine with my test account except for one little thing, orientation.

My app is in landscape and the screen generated by the PayPal lib is portrait, when I move back from the PayPal screen to my app the views are still all in landscape but the status bar moves to portrait, thus leaving a space where the bar usually sits and cutting off the left hand side of the view with the status bar.

I'm not doing anything strange code-wise just the normal orientation methods shown below. Any advice appreciated :)

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:FALSE];
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }`

Comment: Can we use paypal API in iphone app..I am confused to using it because some say app will be reject and some says you can use . can we use paypal API in app ?

Comment: @GhostRider - See here for discussion about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd come back and give an update to this one. I never did figure out how to fix this but it seems to be an OS bug as I've seen it appear in other native Apple apps on the iphone. The youtube app is an example, sometimes switching between portrait and landscape can result in the status bar being in the worg position, pic provided.

I've decided to remove the status bar completely from the app and have it full screen. hope theres's a fix released for this soon!

[image]