# Is it possible to integrate Authorize.net payment gateway in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, authorize.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which kind of Payment gateway can inter available in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869172/which-kind-of-payment-gateway-can-inter-available-in-iphone)
>   [Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

I have good experience of application development in `iPhone`. But i done little work with payment gateways. I have been working with `Paypal` gateway. I want to integrate authorize.net api in iphone. So if anybody can idea about it. please give me reference.

Comment: Just be aware that Apple aren't exactly appreciative of external payments, unless it's related to physical goods.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in objective C please have a look here:

> figured this out after some heavy API research. Below is a method that creates an HTTP POST to send to Paypal and makes an NSURLRequest. You can fill in the appropriate string format variables. I used HTTP Client to check what I was doing.
>   [PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app/850940#850940)

Comment: it will be rejected by App Store as per my knowledge.