# Questions around handling payments within my iPhone/iPad app. Will Apple reject?

Tags: iphone, ipad, appstore-approval, payment-processing

I am currently building an app for an existing and large Royalty Free music library.  They sell stock music to be used in productions/websites/commercials etc.  What they sell is the license to use the music in your production.

What they want to build is an iPhone and iPad app that is basically an extension of their website.  Users can browse and purchase music through the app.  I am building a web service to connect to the existing website and will most likely use Webview to handle payment via PayPal.  The user is then sent a download link for their music via email after successful purchase

The question I have is whether Apple will reject due to the way we are selling goods.  This is an already established business and the iphone apps are just an extension of that.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you sold using in-app purchase (30% to Apple) they would probably accept it.  Otherwise not, and you should stick with a web app (which you could highly customize for the iPhone/iPad).

Comment: It should be noted that in-app purchases must be consumed in the app. You can't use the in-app purchase feature to buy products which aren't downloaded to the app. Conversely if you offer products which are used in the app you must use in-app purchase (and you can have other methods of purchasing the in-app content as well)

Comment: Yes, we can't use in-app purchase as the content needs to be consumed outside the app.  How do other commerce stores get round this?

Comment: Well, the Kindle app existing before in-app purchase so who knows. I'm just quoting from the App Store review guidelines.

Comment: That's a good point Chili, probably would not work as in-app purchase either.

Comment: It's still a grey area for me.  As if we were selling physical CDs then it is allowed.  We are selling a 'license' rather than music so maybe they let it through?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely would get rejected. One option might be to use the iPhone app to browse and sample the tracks, but link out to a mobile safari web page to complete the transaction.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems the most likely scenario.  If I just opened up Webview within the app it would get rejected?

Comment: Probably. Apple would still look at that as "in app", as would most users.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely get rejected.
My app had a link to our website that had a puchase link. They rejected the app for that too.
Buying directly from the app is not allowed.