# How to test paypal sandbox in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to paypal and currently implementing paypal in my iphone app. I have successfully integrated the MPL library and its working fine. Now I need to  test the payment mechanism works or not. How can I test this?

1. I already have a paypal account. i tried to use this but got a
   message Login Failed. Please try again.
2. Do I need to create a sandbox paypal id ?
3. How to create a paypal Id for business to use in sandbox
       environment?

Can some one please provide more details.

Comment: for knowing all of this please visit this queiston and it's answer is best solution for you my friend..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940985/can-i-use-paypal-in-iphone-ipad-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You need to create accounts in sandbox mode.You can create test accounts [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts).

And You can seee sandbox notifications [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/dashboard/email)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: also check this:-http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: Thanks @BSThakrar . I already have a paypal account. I clicked the login with paypal option. Now I am in the developers portal. As I mentioned before I am using paypal in IOS. Do i need to create an application? What are the ClientID and Secretkey. As far as I know I am initializing paypal with an appId. IS client Id same as appId for test environment? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Yes, You need to create app in developer.paypal.com. By creating app you wil get both clientId and secret key. As far as i know you will only need clientId to perform transection.

Comment: I used the client Id. But with that the pay With PayPal option is disabled!!

Comment: I am not sure why that happened. I used clientId and it's working for me. you set environment as PayPalEnvironmentSandbox,right ?