# App Store and external links

Tags: app-store, appmobi

I am a bit confused about this. I am using Appmobi to develop a photo app. The customer uploads some photos from his device and order several copies (it's for a small local photo store)

Well, I see that if I want to pay the order inside the app, Apple gets the 30% of it (this store gains around 15%), so this model is not possible. I found that I can launch an external link from the app (in Appmobi framework via AppMobi.device.launchExternal or AppMobi.device.showRemoteSite) I can place the order on a server and launch an external link with the info to Paypal, but... Does anyone know if this break the Apple TOS? The store sells a physical object (photos), so I think this is permitted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'd have a hard time getting something like that approved.  Apple is very reluctant to approve any links to Paypal or other external payment providers, even for small businesses providing local goods.  What you could do instead, is have the customer pay for the photos in the store, or increase the price to account for Apple's 30% cut.  I don't have experience selling local goods like that, but I am fairly positive Apple won't allow that.  You can always try, though!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Charging the 30% on the customer is not possible, because then he will be less competitive, and the idea is to send the photos to customer's home.

Comment: Another option you could consider is allowing credit card payments in the application itself.  There are a couple open-source libraries out there that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand

If a service can be consumed by your phone (Digital/Virtual goods etc) there're restrictions on how you can pay. (Apple will almost always require you to pay using IAP or not provide a system for payments at all (i.e. users will top-up on a website, but the app can't have a link pointing users to it. Checkout Kindle, Skydrive etc.)

If a service can't be consumed on the phone itself (physical items like printed photos) then you can't use IAP for payments and must you external payment providers such as Paypal et al.

There're examples on this similar post [If I use the PayPal gateway in my iPhone app, will Apple approve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005929/if-i-use-the-paypal-gateway-in-my-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-it)