# iOS payment gateway other than in-App

Tags: iphone, ios5, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I have an iphone application, in which there is online payment feature. For payment i want to use my own payment gateway which is on website. So that i can redirect user to website for payment. Can anyone help me please, will apple allow this feature or not?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005929/if-i-use-the-paypal-gateway-in-my-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-it

Comment: Thnks matt for quick reply!    I just need to pay for online ticket booking on website.

Comment: If it could be considered as Physical good then you can implement external gateway; else not.

Comment: You can ask for this at: `appreview@apple.com` -- as it was in answer provided in my very first comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope of the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 5):

Apple allows 3rd party payment gateway system. There are some good solutions provided by Stripe, Authorize.NET or Zooz.

Stripe (http://www.stripe.com) is a really good payment gateway for iOS. They will do credit card validations and return the token to your iOS app. You will then do order verifications to your website and finally submit the charges to stripe.

This is a really good tutorial on using Stripe with iOS:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stripe is not universal right? not working in some countries