# iOS Payment integration

Tags: ios, iphone, payment-gateway

I am working on iOS app where user can participate in contest and win cash prize.

Can anyone help me how can I send this cash to user via any payment system integration on iphone application.

Comment: Uhh... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608755/ios-payment-gateway-other-than-in-app), perhaps?

Comment: Integrate your app with Paypal.. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/ .. take a look