# iOS paypal API - Apple Rejection

Tags: ios, ios4, paypal

I want to develop one iPhone app in which user upload their documents on my server and then I will process that documents and provide them back via mail or any other mechanism out side of app.

I want to integrate Paypal API for the charging user in my app(as a document processing fee).

Does apple allow my app or they will reject my app. if yes then should I need to integrate InApp purchase to avoid rejection from apple?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I'm sure you can find an answer here: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: You may be able to get PayPal past Apple but you won't get it past users. Apps not using secure In App Purchases are almost always instant deletes for a lot of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Apple's system in app purchases](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) if payment will add more content or update something in your App. And else you have aonther option for payment methods as payment not adding functionality rather than buying some in real world. You can integrate [PayPal iOS SDK.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/use-cases/#mobile-payments) also [related Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

Buying a physical item or like your condition booking for particular service is perfectly OK in an app. You can use any gateway you want such as PayPal [as also in related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005929/if-i-use-the-paypal-gateway-in-my-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-it) one more option is [stripe](https://stripe.com/)