# itunes rejected pay pal application ?

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app got rejected as PayPal has been used as payment method. in-app purchase method was suggested by apple. my app uses pay pal to credit user account later user can recharge their mobile phone with this credit. In-App purchase does not support it.  How do I proceed. Please advise

Comment: Short answer is "you can't" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005929/if-i-use-the-paypal-gateway-in-my-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its all depends on what you are selling. If you sell Digital Goods then your App must use In-App purchase. On other hand, if you're selling Real-World goods or services, you must use any other source of payment like paypal.

Apple's [In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) explains which type of products can be sold through their system, and which are forbidden.

Hope it helps you.