# PayPal Integration in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, paypal, payment-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone implemented the PayPal API through a native iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

May be I am repeating this question but I do not have any idea about this.I want to **integrate PayPal into my iPhone native app**. Please help me regarding :-

- How do I integrate PayPal in my iPhone App?
- How to go from a scratch ?
- Are there some good tutorials available on internet ? What are they ?

Regards!!

Comment: At least you'll know upfront why the app was rejected ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using Mobile Express Checkout. All the info, [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/mobile-express-checkout-library-ios). Its very easy to integrate within your app. You will need a server side app though to make some of the Paypal calls, as it would not be safe to make them from the phone.