# How to integrate paypal preauth in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, pre-authentication

I am able to integrate pay-pal preauthorize functionality payment forms on my website using the name value hidden variable payment-action=authorization . How can I achieve this pay-pal preauthorize functionality for my iPhone app? What is the variable for payment-action in i-OS?

Comment: see similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480731/paypal-integration-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: Hi, above links give an overview of PayPal library. My problem is that i have integrated the pay-pal successfully. But, now i want pay-pal preauthorize functionality, by which i can capture 115% or maximum $75 of total. In the website there is one such variable payment-action which can be set as authorization at the time of transaction. But, i am not getting this variable in pay-pal iOS library. Is there any such option?

Comment: sorry dude right now don't have much info about that .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, preauthorization is not supported by version 1.0 of the iOS SDK.