# Is it possible to get paypal credentials while using paypal ios library?

Tags: iphone, paypal, credentials

I am using paypal ios library for transactions. I haven't found any method there to get paypal credentials so I can save them in NSUserdefaults, so that user need not to login again and agin or Is there any way to maintain session to do the same?

Comment: Saving login details to PayPal? Dont do it!

Comment: Do not save sensitive information using NSUSerDefaults! They are easily accessible! Use keychain access instead.

Comment: No, its not allow .For the integration paypal api follow the link below:Link1:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app  Link2:https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

Answer (score 1):

By saving password for any third party software . You are a possible medium for anyone to misuse these features. Only certain companies with high level of trust such as google, apple, Microsoft and others are allowed to do that. Not individual developers like us