# Multiple copies of iPhone app

Tags: iphone

We're brainstorming creating an iphone app (and eventually android) which we want to duplicated for multiple companies within our group.

If we have multiple copies of the same app with different app names, icons, background graphics but functioning the same and sending payment to the same paypal account.

Would Apple have a problem with us submitting multiple copies of what in essence is the same application but different businesses?

Thanks for any advice
David

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, there should not be a problem.

We have released several apps that are looking the same, with only different colors and different content.

That said,  Apple have been rejecting for many other different reasons.  Many that we have not been able to predict.  But one problem I would investigate is your Paypal usecase and if Apple would allow it.

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850940/63678)